# Hyperlinks and renaming sheets

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I try to make my hyperlinks future-proof as some sheets containing cells which are the target of hyperlinks.

I have two sheets

```
sheetA sheetB
```

`sheetB` contains hyperlinks like

```
=HYPERLINK("#sheetA.C3")
```

If I rename `sheetA` to `renamedSheet` the hyperlinks in `sheetB` are broken. Further autoincrementing via mouse is broken too.

How can I fox this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out:

```
=HYPERLINK("#" & CELL("address";$sheetA.C3))
```